# How to handle missing values to use collective classifier in weka

Tags: weka

I am trying to use a YATSI method in combination of NaiveBayesMultinomial classifier. I have a dataset where are some instances annotated by class. Other instances has missing class ?.

If I try to run YATSI, I will get an error "Cannot handle missing values..."

Could you please help me how to fix it?

Thank you
Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Missing value issue**
Use the ReplaceMissingValues filter in Weka. Detail about the class can be found [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/ReplaceMissingValues.html)

**Missing class issue**
Those are your test instances. You need to build classifiers and then apply on these instances with '?' tags to provide them a class label.

Comment: So, If I want to use YATSI properly, the train set is a set of labeled instances and the test set contains all unlabeled instances, right? I have dataset of 1 000 users and 200 users are annotated. 100 anomalous and 100 normal and I am trying to find next anomalous users via this semi-supervised method. In this case, my train model will be that 200 users and test set unlabeled 800 users, right? And the method helps me to predict classes for remaining 800 users in test set, right? Thank you for your feedback. I am new in using semi-supervised methods. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes that is correct for any supervised learning problem. Semi supervised is a diiferent issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused now. I wrote about using YATSI as a semi-supervised method and meaning how to use the method correctly. And you wrote that semi-supervised is a different issue - now I am confused if I understand the using YATSI correctly and my "usage procedure" is OK. Thank you. Petr

Comment: The inability to run with missing values has a common solution like using the filter I mentioned in my solution. The missing class also has the interpretation that I provided. You wanted a fix for these. If I understand correctly, then whether your "usage procedure" is wrong or right should have a different answer and thread.